# New to reading kit music - questions about technique

Tags: notation, technique, drum-kits

I’m a self taught drum kit player and this is my first time reading drum sheet music. I’ve made drum sheets before with MuseScore, so I can read most things fine, but there’s one section where it asks me to play 3 notes at once (a ride, snare, and an unspecified drum played with the hand I assume to be a tom of some sort).

[image: drum groove with instances of simultaneous notes in the third space (snare drum), fourth space (tom?), and first space above the staff (ride cymbal)]

What does it want from me? Obviously I can’t play 3 drums with 2 hands.

---

Also, it occasionally says “pop” (written in quotations on the sheet music), in reference to a snare drum. What does that mean?

[image: drum groove with "R.S" and "pop" marking below snare hit]

Comment: Can you add an example of such notation, and author and title of the music?

Comment: Sure, I just didn’t want to get in copyright trouble. The title is “Themes from 007 (A Medley for Orchestra) arranged by Calvin Custer

Comment: You can probably play a snare and a rack tom if they are positioned the right way and you use both ends of a stick simultaneously. I can’t say for sure if that is what they are after.

Comment: Drum music, as you've possibly found, is somewhat idiosyncratic. The notation can vary from engraver to engraver. Generally, the higher on the stave, the higher the sound from the drum/cymbal. But that's only a rough guide. I prefer it when there's a legend attached. 'Pop' can be achieved by tuning the batter head as tight as possible. Often then loosening off the snare head and snares themselves. It will depend a lot on the drum and your technique.

Comment: I think the three hits at once notations are mistakes. If the original really sounds like all three are hit, I might just not hit the ride since it has the longest sustain from the previous hit.

Comment: Drum kit notation isn't completely standardised.  If the first space above the staff is being used for the ride cymbal, maybe the fourth space is for the hi-hat.  If so, for the first groove you could play these hi-hat notes with the left foot.

Comment: @elements in space that's an interesting thought, although I would've appreciated it if they told me what it was lol

Comment: @Tim If I tune the batter head tightly for the 'pop' sections what do I do once it asks for the original/ordinary version (I'm assuming that's what ord. means from google)

Comment: @ToddWilcox unfortunately there is no original as this is an arrangement wihtout an official recording.

Comment: If you want/need to be exact, the answer is to use two snare drums. Over the top, for some, but could be seen as authentic for others.

Answer (score 3):

As a percussionist and drum set player, There's some stuff that's just 'wrong' with the sheet music in front of you (using normal as opposed to X noteheads for cymbals, along with your 3 hand instruments at once issue).

I would just pick 2 of the three based on personal taste/your ear. Personally I would very rarely be inclined to play a high tom along with a snare on every two and four, but I'm sure there's some musical context for it somewhere. Listen to some recordings of the piece if possible, ask your bandleader, and play what sounds good (such is the life of a percussionist).

If you still aren't sure, is there a guide/diagram on your music telling you what each line/space on the stave stands for? It might be in the directors score?

Answer (score 0):

The "pop" text goes together with the "R.S." text above it.

R.S. means rimshot, but I think what's probably intended here is a side-stick rather than a rimshot.